uninitialized constant Pod::Podfile::FlipperConfiguration
i have an reactnative app i transfer it from windows to macbook
now when im trying to install pod im getting this error:
[!] Invalid Podfile` file: uninitialized constant Pod::Podfile::FlipperConfiguration.
from /Users/aldines/Documents/samaapp/ios/Podfile:24
-------------------------------------------
# flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug"], { 'Flipper' => '0.250.0' }),

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled


-------------------------------------------`
here my podfile code:
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
# flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
# flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug"], { 'Flipper' => '0.250.0' }),
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled


use_frameworks! :linkage => :static # added by developer


linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Fuzzy' do
  config = use_native_modules!
   # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    #:flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.

    
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'FuzzyTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end



  post_install do |installer|
    # Existing react_native_post_install call
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  
    # Exclude arm64 architecture for iOS Simulator for all targets
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
      end
    end
  end
  
end

i tried to install flipper and to change in the podfile
as you see the command ,and tried solutions from stackoverflow its not working
its just im new user on macbook

Were your able to find a solution? I am having the same issue

yeah i did fix it its all related to Pods,and packages.json,

Can you post a step by step solution?

can you share your error and podfile code to check it
